# Confusing data annotation validation

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, class, data-annotations

I had been struggling with this issue since morning. I have the following class in my domain service.

```
 [MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(CompanyRecord.CompanyRecordMetadata))]
 public partial class CompanyRecord
 {

     // This class allows you to attach custom attributes to properties
     // of the CompanyRecord class.
     //
     // For example, the following marks the Xyz property as a
     // required property and specifies the format for valid values:
     //    [Required]
     //    [RegularExpression("[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]*")]
     //    [StringLength(32)]
     //    public string Xyz { get; set; }
    internal sealed class CompanyRecordMetadata
    {
        // Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
        private CompanyRecordMetadata()
        {
        }

        public Nullable<char> AccessToClearance { get; set; }

        public Nullable<char> AccessToMarketplace { get; set; }

        public Nullable<bool> Active { get; set; }

        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> AllotedHDSpace { get; set; }

        public string City { get; set; }

        public int CompanyID { get; set; }

        public Binary CompanyLogo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Company Name is required and must be unique.")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }

        [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Company Type is required.")]
        public int CompanyTypeID { get; set; }

        [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Country is required.")]
        public Nullable<int> CountryID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(pattern: @"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|tv|COM|ORG|NET|GOV|MIL|BIZ|INFO|MOBI|NAME|AERO|JOBS|MUSEUM|TV|Com|Org|Net|Gov|Mil|Biz|Info|Mobi|Name|Aero|Jobs|Museum|Tv)\b", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid email address")]
        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.[a-zA-z]{2,6})", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid email address")]
        public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }

        //[RegularExpression(pattern: @"[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|tv|COM|ORG|NET|GOV|MIL|BIZ|INFO|MOBI|NAME|AERO|JOBS|MUSEUM|TV|Com|Org|Net|Gov|Mil|Biz|Info|Mobi|Name|Aero|Jobs|Museum|Tv)\b", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid email address")]
        //(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.\w{2,3})
        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"(\w[-._\w]*\w@\w[-._\w]*\w\.[a-zA-z]{2,6})", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid email address")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Phone Ext. should not be more than 10 chars.")]
        public string EmployeePhoneExt { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Phone No. should not be more than 20 chars.")]
        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"^[0-9\-\(\) ]*[0-9\-\(\)]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid Phone No.")]
        public string EmployeePhoneNo { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Number of projects should be lower than 2,147,483,647.")]
        public Nullable<int> NoOfProjects { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> NoOfUsers { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Phone Ext. should not be more than 10 chars.")]
        public string PhoneExt { get; set; }

        [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "Phone No. should not be more than 20 chars.")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone No. is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"^[0-9\-\(\) ]*[0-9\-\(\)]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please provide a valid Phone No.")]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        [RegularExpression(pattern: @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\(\)\* ]*[a-zA-Z0-9\-\(\)\*]*$", ErrorMessage = "Postal codes cant' contain special characters except for -, (, ), * and spaces.")]            
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        public string Province { get; set; }

        public string Website { get; set; }

        public int MarketID { get; set; }

        public int AffiliationID { get; set; }

        public string CallLetter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PROBLEM: I need to create a validation rule that woudl require MarketID and Affiliation ID only when CompanyTypeID is equivalent to 1, 3, 5, 9 and 11 is there someone out there who has an idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the custom validation.
There are some topics for your question below:

1 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute(vs.95).aspx

2 http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2009/04/14/net-ria-services-custom-validation.aspx

Comment: Hi @forever, I've been experiencing the same scenario with sheila.. but the problem that occurs for me is that whenever I'm calling dataform.validateitem the method inside the custom validation for my entity is not being called, instead it was being called later after dataform.validateitem() had been evaluated.

Comment: Hellow @AllanChua,you may notice the binding updatetrigger of your textbox of dataform.